# How to create Scala project in proper way?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I would like to create project in scala, with proper directory structure, test directory etc. I'm completly new in Java stuff, so please tell me how to do it? Which tools (maven?) should I use? How to place test and configure them to see my project classes? I use eclipse as IDE. Any help - web resources, links I will appreciate :)

Comment: Meanwhile I have learned that I should use maven, ant or stb.

Comment: It's actually `sbt` and you should use that, not maven or ant (if possible)

Comment: I use `maven` all the time for scala projects because I'm working in a Java environment.  It works great.  You'd probably have a lot of problems with `ant`.  It's biggest problem is that it is too flexible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most scala programmers use [sbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt), which by the way is also part of the [Typesafe Stack](http://typesafe.com/stack)

To create a project with it please follow the [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Welcome)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, you should probably use [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) to generate your Eclipse project files. Then just import it (Import/General/Import existing project).